# Is this solution correct? [Discrete-time signals and systems]

Tags: signal-processing

Consider this question taken from Oppenheim - Discrete-time Signal and Systems:

[image: Question]

Now consider its solution (from the Solutions manual)

[image: Solution]

My question is: is the solution for itens (a) and (b) valid? It considers a sequence with only one sample in both cases, how this can be a general solution? If it's valid, based on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in (a) is correct because it was specified in the question itself that $x[x]=\delta[n]$, where $\delta[n]$ is the *unit discrete impulse* (i.e., Kronecker's Delta). The solution in (b), however, is not general *per se* and you are correct in this point.

The linearity of the system must be proved by giving the input $x[n] = a x_1[n] + b x_2[n]$ and verifying that the output is $y[n] = a y_1[n] + b y_2[n]$, where $y_1[n]$ is the output of $x_1[n]$ and $y_2[n]$ is the output of $x_2[n]$. Doing this requires some computation (since you need to do the recursion), but it can be done. However, there is a more clever way to do this: if you re-read the recursion as $y[n] = x[n] + ny[n-1]$, after little computation, we can observe that
$$
y[0] = x[0] \\
y[1] = x[1] + x[0] \\
y[2] = x[2] + 2(x[1] + x[0]) \\
y[3] = x[3] + 3x[2] + 6(x[1]+x[0]) \\
y[4] = x[4] + 4x[3] +12x[2] +24(x[1]+x[0]) \\
y[5] = x[5] + 5x[4] +20x[3] +60x[2] + 120(x[1] +x[0]) \\
\cdots \\
y[n] = x[n] + n x[n-1] + n(n-1) x[n-2] + n(n-1)(n-2) x[n-3] + \dots + n!(x[1]+x[0])
$$
that is,
$$
y[n] = \sum_{m=0}^{n} c_{m,n} x[n-m]
$$
for appropriate constants $c_{m,n}$. And the linearity of the system is now clear and follows immediately.